# debugging groovy script elasticsearch

Tags: debugging, groovy, elasticsearch

How is it possible to print or log some variables using a groovy script for scoring?
I know there are log directories, but they don't log what I print in the script.

Comment: For testing if my algorithm work correcty. Or I better say it doesn't and I don't know why. I need to have a look at the variables which I obtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as you said, Here is my way of doing so.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search" -d'
{
    "size": 1, 
    "script_fields": {
       "toTestField": {
          "script": "_source.field_name.equals('key')? true : false "
       }
    }

}'
```

Change the script and Check the value of **toTestField** in response,

I think it is easy way to debug.

Comment: Thank you. It isn't the easiest way. I expectet it to be simpler, but it will work.

Comment: Yaa, I do it like this, And I feel easy doing this.